# Question Regarding Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:{\Bbb R}\to {\Bbb R}$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2$.

(i) Define an open set $U$ such that $f(U)$ is not an open set.

(ii) Define $V$ such that $V$ is not an open set, but $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set.

Would $U = (-2,-1)$ work for (i)?

I am a little lost on (ii), any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: No, $f$ maps $(-2,-1)$ to $(1,4)$, which is open

Comment: What is the inverse image of $[0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i)$ I will say $U=(-1,1)$, then $f(U)=[0,1)$.

For $ii)$ let $V=[0,1)$, them $f^{-1}(V)=(-1,1)$

Answer (score 1):

For $(i)$, you need to take advantage of the fact that $f$ "folds" the negative number-line onto the positive one. So, any open interval around zero will be mapped into a half-closed interval. For $(ii)$, you can simply take advantage of $(i)$ and take $V = f(U)$.